# Doesnt' follow PyTorch's LRScheduler API - Rewrite function into lambda (lr_lambda)

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Is there anyone to know how to rewrite the following lr_lambda `def` into `Lambda` format

```
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import LambdaLR

def cosine_scheduler(optimizer, training_steps, warmup_steps):
    def lr_lambda(current_step):
        if current_step < warmup_steps:
            return current_step / max(1, warmup_steps)
        progress = current_step - warmup_steps
        progress /= max(1, training_steps - warmup_steps)
        return max(0.0, 0.5 * (1.0 + math.cos(math.pi * progress)))
    return LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda)
```

I can only come up with the first part

```
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import LambdaLR

def cosine_scheduler(optimizer, training_steps, warmup_steps):
    lambda current_step : current_step / max(1, warmup_steps) if current_step < warmup_steps else ...

    return LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the lambda function as follows:

```py
fn = lambda current_step: current_step / max(1, warmup_steps) if current_step < warmup_steps else max(0.0, 0.5 * (1.0 + math.cos(math.pi * ((current_step - warmup_steps) / max(1, training_steps - warmup_steps)))))
```